# tensorflow gradient: unsupported operand type

Tags: tensorflow

I got the following error:

anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py:90: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
trainstep = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(lossobj)
```

File "anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 196, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 253, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 469, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 504, in _ExtractImagePatchesGrad
    rows_out = int(ceil(rows_in / stride_r))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'long'

there is look like gather ops is wrong.

Comment: This looks surprising. How do you build your lossobj?

Comment: @user1454804 Because my input placeholder for weight and height (shape[1] & [2]) I set with None to handle dynamic input size.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old issue, but I have found a quick work-around for some cases of this.  Chances are, you are feeding your input using a placeholder and one of the dimensions of the placeholder shape is "None".  If you set that dimension to your batch size, it will no longer be an unknown shape.